# Let $E$ be an extension of $F$ and let $a,b\in E$. Prove that $F(a,b)=F(a)(b)=F(b)(a)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

> Let $E$ be an extension of $F$ and let $a,b\in E$. Prove that $F(a,b)=F(a)(b)=F(b)(a)$.

My thought process is to assume $a,b\in F$, then use the associative property of multiplication.  Seems simple... too simple.

Comment: No it's not about the associative property.  You have to show rational functions in $a$ and $b$ with coefficients in $F$ give the same space as rational functions in $a$ with coefficients given by rational functions in $b$.

Comment: @GregoryGrant, I seem to be at a loss as to how to do that currently.  Can you point me the the right direction?